# jQuery dealing id="q1" and id="q10" as same

Tags: jquery, html

I am calling (from jQuery) divs with `id="q0"`, `id="q1`"... `id="q10"` one by one.
But when it(jQuery) calls **div="q1"** it also calls **div="q10"** simultaneously.

Using characters at the end also didn't work.

```
//jquery
$( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".container").hide();
        var number=0;
        var question="question";
        var question_number=question.concat(number);
        $('[id*='+question_number+']').show();
    $(".submit").click(function (e)
    {
        $(".container").hide();
        number++;
        var question_number=question.concat(number);
        alert(question_number);
        $('[id*='+question_number+']').show();
    });

    });
////////////////html
<div id="question1" class="container">
    <button  class="submit">submit</button>
</div>
/////SO ON
<div id="question10" class="container">
    <button  class="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your jquery code

Comment: use `$('#'+question_number)`, the attribute selector you're using only checks for a partial match

Comment: DJDavid98. Thank you that solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`*=` attribute substring selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) will match any element whose attribute **contains** what you give it. So `[id*=1]` will match **any** element whose `id` attribute contains `1`, which will of course be `question1` and also `question10` (and `foo717`).

To hide a single specific question, use an ID selector: `$("#question" + question_number)`